# mysql inner join ambigious USING() field but not always

Tags: mysql, join, ambiguous

I've recently changed servers and although I'm still apparently using MySQL, I don't think it's the same version or set up in the same way that I'm used to.

The most pronounced effect is on my JOIN queries, essentially some queries that use INNER JOINs are throwing ambigious column errors where on my last server I'm sure the code would be fine.

```
table1
t1_id int primary key
name text

map
t1_id int 
t2_id int 

table2
t2_id int primary key
name text
```

table1 has a one to many relationship with table2.
Normally, to get a row from table1 and all its table2 entries, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN map USING(t1_id) 
INNER JOIN table2 USING(t2_id) 
WHERE table1.t1_id=1;
```

However this throws an ambigious column error every time. The only way round this is to use

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN map ON(table1.t1_id=map.t1_id) 
INNER JOIN table2 ON(map.t2_id=table2.t2_id)
WHERE table1.t1_id=1;
```

There isn't much I can tell you about the server config aside from the version, 5.1.56-community-log, and I beleive it's running Linux (probably Debian).

Is this a problem with my queries or a something to do with the version of MySQL we are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT table1.t1_id, table1.name FROM table1 
INNER JOIN map USING(t1_id) 
INNER JOIN table2 USING(t2_id) 
WHERE table1.t1_id=1;
```

Comment: Tried this and it works. So does my original query that was broken until recently... I'm marking this as accepted because although this didn't actually fix anything I can't reproduce the bug I was seeing earlier so it's either down to human error or someone's gone and fixed the server while I was working on this problem. Thanks anyway, although I should point out that joining two tables while only getting data from one isn't very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can get any coulmn you want from any table, just alias (temp. rename) those that have same names:

```
SELECT table1.t1_id
     , table1.name   AS t1_name
     , table2.t2_id  
     , table2.name   AS t2_name
FROM table1 
  INNER JOIN map USING(t1_id) 
  INNER JOIN table2 USING(t2_id) 
WHERE table1.t1_id=1;
```